# React native Calendar Picker invalid argument supplied to oneOfType

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using `react-native-calendar-picker` from [github](https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker#complex-example-changing-fonts-and-colors-language-and-etc) to use a calendar in my app. The problem it's that everytime I run it, I get some warnings like:
[image]

As seen there, there's something about  `node_modules\react-native-calendar-picker\CalendarPicker\DaysGridView.js` , and there are 4 warning, with `rows` 254,255,256 and 248. Going to that file, I found that those lines are:
[image]
So, the problems seems to be somewhere at `selectedRangeStartStyle, selectedDayStyle and selectetRangeStyle` which I have setted in my componenet with `#XXXXXX`, as hex color codes. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same warning because of those lines. It was a change introduced by this commit https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker/commit/081a07f6c95fc178d17295ef0cd3f68f2b7d117f to fix this issue https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker/issues/246

[Reverting the changes locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulJrC.png) on the file stopped the error from popping up in my console, but that is just a quick workaround i found for now only.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this workaround and get back to you!

Comment: Apparently whoever introduced this change is aware of this new problem (as mentioned here https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker/issues/253#issuecomment-726067741)

and plans to solve it but so far the package keeps on raising this warning when using the selectedDay/selectedRange property.

Component and these props work fine to me, because it is not a full fledged error or bug, ... but it's annoying getting that popping up in the console and in the simulator -_-

Comment: I have tried the workaround above. Indeed, the `warning` dissapeared, but reappeared when I opened the calendar.

Comment: Commenting the lines only temporarily solves the problem since if we update, it will happen again ... Strange that we cannot solve the problem in a cleaner way, what do you think?